# literature on total expectation Poisson-Gamma

Tags: conditional-expectation, empirical-bayes

Having the poisson gamma model:
$$\lambda\sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$$
$$N|\lambda \sim Poiss(\lambda)$$

the expectation of N is $$E(N)=E(E(N|\lambda))=E(\lambda)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$

Is there some literature, where I can learn, how to work with such concepts? E.g. what is $E(E(N\lambda))$?

Comment: One question. Do you want to learn how to treat with conditional expectations, or how to treat with Poisson processes?

Comment: I would be interested in how to treat with conditional expectations. In particular, the Poisson-Gamma model.

Comment: I can recommend a book by Kingman "Poisson Processes". For conditional expectation there are tones of literature which contain  conditional expectation. The most easy introduction I have seen was written  "Elementary Stochastic Calculus" (by Thomas Mikosch). A good book you to look through would be the one by Taylor and Karlin, "An introduction to stochastic modelling". You may want to take a look at the following chapters ("Conditioning of random variable" and "Spatial Poisson processes" as far as I remember).

Comment: I would also like to mention my favorite lecture notes. A very thorough work by Amir Dembo named "Stochastic processes".

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations.